# What is Sublimes CMD + D equivalent in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Ive been writing swift for months without this answer, and can't find it online.  CMD + D is too useful a command in sublime to not have an Xcode equivalent.  Can anyone please tell me what it is.

Comment: Depends what you want to do. If you want to select the next instance of the currently selected text, do Command-E Command-G. If you want to edit all occurrences of the currently selected term (e.g. because you want to change a local variable name throughout), do Control-Command-E (one of my personal favorites).

Comment: It might be helpful to tell people what `CMD + D` does. not everybody has used sublime, but may yet know the answer.

Comment: `CMD + D` selects the word at current cursor position and if you press it multiple times, it selects the next occurrences

Answer (score 7):

From at least Xcode 12.4 and above, this functionality is available as "Select Next Occurrence" in the "Find" menu, and as `Option + CMD + E`.

Select some text. Hit `Option + CMD + E` to add the next occurrence, resulting in multiple cursors so you can edit all of them at once.

Comment: I have been looking this for ages, thanks for sharing it .

Comment: Thank you!  It's not perfect, it does nothing if no text is selected (not sure about Sublime, but in any JetBrains IDE, Select Next Occurrence will select the word containing the cursor if nothing is selected, which is SO useful), but it is so much better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this feature in Xcode, so I build it as an Xcode extension lol.

Please try! https://github.com/hlung/XcodeExtensions